# Good Javascript Combo Box replacement for combo boxes with tons of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, dhtml

I have a page where my combo box has hundreds of elements which makes it very hard to pick the one item I want. Is there a good Javascript replacement that would do better than

```
<select id="field-component" name="field_component"> 
                  <option selected="selected">1</option><option>2</option>...
</select>
```

Is there something with "Intellisense"-like auto-complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: http://www.dhtmlx.com/images/logo_combo.gif]
You have [dhtmlCombo](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml), using ajax to retrieve data when you are filling the input field.

dhtmlxCombo is a cross-browser JavaScript combobox with autocomplete feature.

It extends basic selectbox functionality to meet the requirements of the most up-to-date web applications.

dhtmlxCombo can be converted from existing HTML SELECT or populated with JavaScript. Supporting AJAX, it can also **get list values from the server datasource dynamically**.

Comment: Best I've seen. Too bad it is not free though :(

Answer (score 6):

In HTML 5 there's standard combo box.

Currently only Opera supports it, but if you happen to be time traveller or writing Opera-only application, it's a nice solution :)

```
<input type=text list=listid>
<datalist id=listid>
  <select><option>1<option>2</select>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-autocomplete) plugin, it's easy to use, you only have to generate a JSON response server side.

See [this demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

The [autocompleter](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/ajax-autocompleter) using [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) and [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) works well in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: If the select box is current focused, you can type on your keyboard and it will take you to the selection beginning with that text, so typing "k-e-n" into a US State dropdown would auto-select the "Kentucky" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this combobox realization http://www.zoonman.com/projects/combobox/

- Pure JavaScript. Editable. Supports IE6.
- Nonstandard HTML layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think Twitter's free `typeahead.js` library is the best autocomplete library available today. Check it out at http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/