# How to perform textbox and dropdownlist in one control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, textbox, drop-down-menu

For example : I have UserID and UserName. So I use DropDownList. UserName is DataTextField
and UserID is DataValueField. So User can choose their name and I save UserID to my database.
But If User is new and not registered. I want to allow to type in DropDownList and I save the name to database. So for registered people can choose and not registered people can key in.

How should I do? Can anybody give me suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an editable dropdown:

http://www.google.com.au/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=editable%20dropdown&meta=

[How can I create an editable dropdownlist in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511458.aspx

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx