# dropdown menu html form personalized category

Tags: javascript, html, forms, menu, drop-down-menu

i have the following part of code of a dropdown menu

```
<p>
<label for='Select a Category '>Select a Category<font color="red"><strong>*</strong></font>: </label></p> 
<p><div id='contactform_category_errorloc' class='err'></div>

  <select name="category" class="input">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">
      [choose yours]
    </option>
    <option value="Arts and entertainment">Arts and entertainment</option>
    <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
    <option value="Games">Games</option>
    <option value="Health">Health</option>
    <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
    <option value="News and Media">News and Media</option>
    <option value="Recreation">Recreation</option>
    <option value="Reference">Reference</option>
    <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="World">World</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

i want add in drop down menu an option with value: "custom" that when i select this option appear just below a field blank as input text  where i can add my personalized text so i can insert personalized category
it's possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you mean something like this: http://jsbin.com/ubihuw/edit#javascript,html
so in php or something you can check then the "my_own_text" field ... dont know what you will exactly do ;)

js:

```
$('.input').change(function()
{
  if($(this).attr('value') == "0") {
    $('#choose_own_text').append('<input type="text" id="my_own_text" name="my_own_text" value="Please type in .." />');
  } else {
    $('#choose_own_text').empty();
  }
});
```

your code ...

```
<p><div id='contactform_category_errorloc' class='err'></div>

  <select name="category" class="input">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">
      [choose yours]
    </option>
    <option value="Arts and entertainment">Arts and entertainment</option>
    <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
    <option value="Games">Games</option>
    <option value="Health">Health</option>
    <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
    <option value="News and Media">News and Media</option>
    <option value="Recreation">Recreation</option>
    <option value="Reference">Reference</option>
    <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="World">World</option>
  </select>
  <div id="choose_own_text"></div>
</p>
```