# Event handler for input+datalist

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-datalist

I'd like to use something like [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658653/174728)

```
<input type="text" name="product" list="productName"/>
<datalist id="productName">
    <option value="Pen">Pen</option>
    <option value="Pencil">Pencil</option>
    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
</datalist>
```

But I need to run some js code whenever the selection is changed (or the value edited). Is there a way to hook up an event handler for that?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/onchange) event?

Comment: @Aiias, that's the behaviour I want, but it doesn't apply to `<input>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**input** event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) would work. The **change** event works as well, but it is only triggered when the `input` element looses focus, not every time the value changes.

```
document.querySelector('input').oninput = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4rF5/)

Comment: It seems to fire all the time on chrome (when I click on an item or type a key). Maybe other browsers work differently? I should be able to work with this.

Comment: Well, it fires when the input changes. In contrast, the change event only fires when the input looses focus and the value changed.

Comment: Oh right, I just didn't read your answer properly :) I guess you made those bits bold for me

Comment: I did :) I figured it might not be clear if one just quickly reads over it.